# Why NumPy and pandas packages are always problematic when setting up first time Python interpreter as Anaconda provided

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pycharm, anaconda

Below is simple Line of code to try NumPy

```
import numpy as np

my_list = [1, 2, 3]
print(my_list)
print(type(my_list))  

my_list_arr = np.array(my_list)  # Here we are converting python list to numpy array
print(my_list_arr)
print(type(my_list_arr))
```

My question is: when I execute above lines of code using Jupyter-Notebook , it works well without any package issues BUT Why same line of code throwing NumPy , pandas and other package dependencies  related  issues  when execute on PyCharm as .py file

FYI,
my setup of PyCharm project as;

python interpreter  --> pointed to Anaconda provided

created PyCharm virtual environment   - venv

Inherit-global-site-packages – Yes

Please help me. I am  fed up with installing packages using conda and tired of doing package corrections one by one as and when ERRORs comes one after another package.
Any Better Solution please  !!

Below is Error by Pycharm

```
D:\Mytech\IDE_workspace\PycharmProjects\python_anaconda_base_venv_and_global_site_packages\venv\Scripts\python.exe D:/Mytech/IDE_workspace/PycharmProjects/python_anaconda_base_venv_and_global_site_packages/python_for_data_science/my_NumPyArrays_practice.py
C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py:143: UserWarning: mkl-service package failed to import, therefore Intel(R) MKL initialization ensuring its correct out-of-the box operation under condition when Gnu OpenMP had already been loaded by Python process is not assured. Please install mkl-service package, see http://github.com/IntelPython/mkl-service
  from . import _distributor_init
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\multiarray.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\overrides.py", line 7, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _multiarray_umath: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Mytech\IDE_workspace\PycharmProjects\python_anaconda_base_venv_and_global_site_packages\python_for_data_science\my_NumPyArrays_practice.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 145, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.9 from "D:\Mytech\IDE_workspace\PycharmProjects\python_anaconda_base_venv_and_global_site_packages\venv\Scripts\python.exe"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.20.3"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: DLL load failed while importing _multiarray_umath: The specified module could not be found.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

but when i am executing below code it showing. it working.

```
import sys

print("******************************")
print("This Code using:")
print("Python Version       =", sys.version)
print("Python Interpreter   =", sys.base_prefix)
print("*******************************")

print("*******************************")
This Code using:
Python Version       = 3.9.7 (default, Sep 16 2021, 16:59:28) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Python Interpreter   = C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3
print("*******************************")

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: The provided example code throws a `pandas` *and other package* related exception? Please include this error traceback in the question.

Comment: Just edited and added Error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60585818/what-does-it-mean-to-inherit-global-site-packages-in-pycharm), the `inherit-global-site-packages` inherits from your *Global* python install. This is the install that comes with your machine or is installed "directly" into `/usr/bin` or the Windows equivalent. I don't think pointing the interpreter to Anaconda will make it inherit from Anaconda, because Anaconda is not considered a global python install.

What is happening is you are inheriting from a python install that you probably did not install anything to. I can think of two solutions:

1. Install the packages you want in your *global* python install (running `which python` or `which python3` outside of a conda env should show you where that is; after finding the command that calls the global python, pip install using that command)
2. Use conda environments, and just set your interpreter to different conda environments, instead of making a PyCharm env. If you are not familiar with this, you can run `conda create -n NAME python=X.XX` where NAME is what you want to name the environment and X.XX is the version number. From there, you can `conda activate NAME`, and then either pip or conda install your packages.

Comment: Thanks. sami-amer .. let me try it. 
when i went to File>settings>python interpreter then I could see all package which comes with anaconda installations (ie. conda) . so i made a concept that inherit-global-site-packages (✓)  is enabling PyCharm to access site-packages  of interpreter used whether its 
Pypi installation or Anadonda installation.  
But now i think, its wrong concept i am building, so i'll change it. But interestingly, not sure why PyCharm Shows those packages from  C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3 .. if PyCharm is not able to access  it then should not show it.